# scala - immutability performances

Tags: scala

**Note:** Even though I'll be using Akka tutorial code as a test case, my question is about Scala immutability performances in general, and how to tune JVM consequently

I'm approaching Akka and I was trying out its tutorial code [Akka getting started](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html); I pasted source code as-is from the tutorial to my own project and ran it, obtaining this output:

```
Calculation time:       660 milliseconds
```

After this, I tried working a little on the code, rewriting this function

```
def calculatePiFor(start: Int, nrOfElements: Int): Double = {
  var acc = 0.0
  for (i <- start until (start + nrOfElements))
    acc += 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1)
  acc
}
```

without using a *var* accumulator, like this

```
def calculatePiFor(start: Int, nrOfElements: Int): Double = {
  val range = start until (start + nrOfElements)
  val computation = range.map(i => 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1))
  computation.sum
}
```

well, it worked but performances kind of degenerated

```
Calculation time:       1737 milliseconds
```

and here come my questions: are there any major mistakes in my function or something that without a doubt lead to these performance? if not, can anyone point out a good rule to tune JVM in order to improve these performances?

I ran my code on Scala 2.9, using sbt 0.12.0 with its default java options (bundled in sbt.bat):

```
_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Answer (score 7):

You will get better performances by using `foldLeft` which will compute the sum in one pass as the imperative example you shown:

```
val computation = range.foldLeft(0.0){
  case (sum,i) => sum + 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1))
}
```

But, it may still be slower than its imperative counterpart. If it **really is** the bottleneck of your application, you should use the fastest version (imperative version with while loops). Its is safe with Actors because the mutable state will be completely isolated.

In all the other cases, better lose a few percent of performance (when measured on your whole application) that to use messy code.

Comment: There’s quite a speedup for this operation in Scala 2.10, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your foldLeft implementation reduced computation time to around 1000 ms, which is a huge gain compared to my previous implementation.
Also, I'm with you in saying that losing a little in performances is a small price to pay in order to have better code, but what I really wanted to find out with my question was whether this perf loss could be somehow reduced with JVM tuning

Comment: @Debilski Which operation ? FoldLeft ?

Comment: @paradigmatic I think `Range.foreach` has been optimised which is used by `Range.foldLeft`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem in your program is the invocation of `range.map(..)` method which is *strict* (non-lazy). That means - if your range has 1000 elements, `map` method will allocate memory for 1000 new elements and compute them all immediately.

So I guess that alternative and very simple way of improving your code would be to use the range view: `range.view.map(..)`, so that mapped elements are computed lazily and constant amount of memory is allocated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try foldLeft instead of map/sum:

```
  def calculatePiFor(start: Int, nrOfElements: Int): Double = {
    val range = start until (start + nrOfElements)
    range.foldLeft(0.0) { (acc,i) => acc + 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1)}
  }
```

I'm guessing this would avoid the need for an intermediate collection and might therefore run faster.